# Como visualizar o "CommandText" com os parametros adicionados?

Tags: c#

```
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("", conexao);
comm.CommandText = ("SELECT @select FROM @from WHERE @where LIKE '@like'");
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@select", select);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", from);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@where", where);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@like", like);
```

Se executo `Debug.WriteLine(comm.CommandText)` o meu retorno é:

`"SELECT @select FROM @from WHERE @where LIKE '@like'"`.

Como visualizar o `CommandText` do conector do MYSQL para C# com os parâmetros adicionados?

Comment: Acho que não tem, você teria que simular fazendo os replaces, dê uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um método estendido para solucionar este problema veja abaixo:

```
public static string GravaLog(this IDbCommand cmd)
    {
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        var nome = cmd.CommandText.ToString();
        builder.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString() + $" {nome}(");

        foreach (IDataParameter item in cmd.Parameters)
        {

            if (i+1 == cmd.Parameters.Count)
            {
                builder.Append($"{item.ParameterName} => '{item.Value.ToString()}'");
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append($"{item.ParameterName} => '{item.Value.ToString()}', ");
                i++;
            }
        }

        builder.Append(");");
       return builder.toString();
    }
```

Neste caso você irá receber um IDbCommand que é herdado no MYSQLCOMMAND, ele vai abrir os parâmetros pegando o nome de cada um juntamente com os valores passados e montar um string. Espero ter ajudado!!!